# Why is a list of kind * -> *?

Tags: haskell

In GHCI, using :info on a list [], will show that it is of kind * -> *

```
Prelude> :i []
type [] :: * -> *
```

How can I reason about this when I can construct a list with multiple elements, e.g. [1, 2, 3]

Comment: The command is `:k []` or `:kind []`. `[]` has kind `* -> *` (or `Type -> Type`) because it is a type constructor that takes one type parameter to become a "list of ...". For example, `:k [Int]`, a case where this parameter has been given, has kind `*` (or `Type`). You can also write it like `:k ([]) Int` to make `[]` into a prefix constructor, after which the syntax of providing the type parameter is more like function application, but at the type level.

Comment: This is odd. Which version of ghc do you have? Perhaps some "set -X..." options are in effect? My `:i []` prints information that would be a bit more useful: `data [] a = [] | a : [a]        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’` and then some info about instances.

Comment: @SimonShine: You can also write `[]` in prefix without parentheses: `[] Int`. Removing the syntactic sugar like this can be handy for explaining things like the `Monad` and `Traversable` instances for lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lists have special syntax in Haskell.

You could define a datatype such as lists yourself, using normal syntax, as

```hs
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

Now note in particular that with this definition, the empty list is written `Nil` rather than `[]`, and that the type of lists of integers is written `List Int` rather than `[Int]`.

If we look at the type of lists of integers, it consists of two components, the `List` and the `Int`. Looking at `List` in isolation, it is a "type constructor", a function on the type-level that takes an argument which is itself a type (such as `Int`) and forms a new type `List Int`. It is useful to be able to talk about `List` without an argument in some circumstances, for example as an argument to other type constructors, or as an argument of type classes such as `Functor` or `Applicative`. Therefore, `List` has kind `* -> *`, because it expects one argument.

For Haskell's built-in list type, as stated above, `List Int` is typically written `[Int]`, but it can *also* be written as `[] Int`, and indeed `[]` corresponds to `List` in isolation, refers to the list type constructor written without being applied to its argument, and it therefore also has kind `* -> *`.

Tuple type constructors are also having special syntax in Haskell. For example, a pair of an integer and a Boolean is typically written as `(Int, Bool)`, but it can *also* be written as `(,) Int Bool`, where `(,)` is the unapplied pair type constructor, and has kind `* -> * -> *`, because it expects two arguments.

Answer (score 5):

First, please forget about those `*` symbols. They're a historic oddity; Haskell is switching to the name `Type` for them. In GHC-8.x, you should turn on the `-XTypeInType` extension to allow that, and `-XNoStarIsType` to disable the old syntax. Then it will read

```
> :k []
[] :: Type -> Type
```

This function arrow has nothing to do with how many elements are to be put in the list, rather it is about what *type of element* is supposed to be contained in the list – and that is always *exactly one type*. The *list values* of that list type will of course be able to contain multiple elements of that contained type

```
       Int ⟼ [Int]        % [3], [74,12,-394], []
      Bool ⟼ [Bool]       % [True], repeat [False]
(Int,Bool) ⟼ [(Int,Bool)] % [(0,False)], [(3,True)]
      Char ⟼ String       % ['y'], "bla bla", ""
```

Contrast this with the [HList](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-HList-HList.html#t:HList) container: *heterogeneous lists* which contain *multiple different* types (exactly one element of each type):

```
> :k HList
HList :: [Type] -> Type
```

And now

```
       '[Int] ⟼ HList '[Int]          % HL[3], HL[-394]
          '[] ⟼ HList '[]             % HL[]
'[Int,String] ⟼ HList '[(Int,String)] % HL[(0,"0")], HL[(1,"one")]
```